# loops / labels with break/continue

Tags: java

Putting the merits of this coding style aside, I have the following piece of code:

```
public static void main(String argvs[]) {

    int i, j;
    Point_1: for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
            if (j == 5)
                continue Point_1;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

With `continue Point_1;`, the output is: `12345123451234512345123451234512345123451234512345`

but with `break Point_1;`, the output is:
`12345`

What's going on? In other words, what's the difference between `continue label;` and `break label;` ?

Comment: Please, for the sake of your fellow programmers, don't ever use labels to break out of loops.

Comment: Wouldn't dream of it, this is really just a programming curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same as the difference between `break` and `continue` in general.

`continue Point_1;` means "skip to the start of the next iteration of the loop labelled `Point_1`".

`break Point_1;` means "break out of the loop labelled `Point_1`".

Here's how they would translate to `goto` statements:

```
int i, j;
Point_1:
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        System.out.print(j);
        if (j == 5) {
            // break Point_1; --> goto Break_Label;
            // continue Point_1; --> goto Continue_Label;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    Continue_Label:
}
Break_Label:
```

Comment: Why does it keep the value of the iterators `i` and `j`? It doesn't work the same as labels in C ?

Comment: What would you expect it to do with the values of variables?

Comment: Well both `for` loops set it to `i = 1` and `j = 1`. `break` and `continue` don't act like a `goto`?

Comment: No when it hits the label, it falls back to the outer loop, so the value of `i` stays in existance and gets incremented, the `j` variable disappears, and won't be initialized again before the inner loop is reached again, so it's 1 again.

Comment: Yeah, they behave pretty much like `goto` statements. `break` is like `goto`-ing out of the loop, `continue` is like `goto`-ing to the end of the loop body.

Comment: Edited the answer to show how both versions would translate to use of `goto`.

Comment: Well breaking out of multiple loops at once is *occasionally* useful and can be a reasonable way of doing things. I can't say I've ever seen `continue` with a label used sensibly though.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah,
You're asking to java to start over when `j==5`.

> `if(j==5)
>   Continue Point_1`

What this means is: Check if `j==5` if it is true `Continue Point_1`.

`Continue Point_1` means : go to the second `i` and start counting for `j` again, and when `j` is `j==5` again it start the third `i` counts `j` to 5 and repeat `i`times )(in this case 10 times, that why you get 12345 ten times).

And what break does is that it asks java to stop when `j==5`